Is it possible to download the existing buildpacks filename ".zip" from cloud Foundry to my local machine?
We have API for Get a Buildpack, but I cant find download option here
Content-Type: application/json

  {
    "guid": "fd35633f-5c5c-4e4e-a5a9-0722c970a9d2",
    "created_at": "2016-03-18T23:26:46Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-17T20:00:42Z",
    "name": "ruby_buildpack",
    "state": "Ready",
    "filename": "ruby_buildpack-cflinuxfs3-v1.2.13.zip",
    "stack": "cflinuxfs3",
    "position": 42,
    "enabled": true,
    "locked": false,
    "metadata": {
      "labels": {},
      "annotations": {}
    },
    "links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "https://api.example.org/v3/buildpacks/fd35633f-5c5c-4e4e-a5a9-0722c970a9d2"
      },
      "upload": {
          "href": "https://api.example.org/v3/buildpacks/fd35633f-5c5c-4e4e-a5a9-0722c970a9d2/upload",
          "method": "POST"
      }
    }
  }

Is there any way to get the filename so that it can be downloaded?

never downloaded a buildpack from CF.
I know you can upload a buildpack with cf create-buildpack java_buildpack_custom ~/Desktop/java-custom.zip 42

@AnthonyDahanne Even I didn't find anything so answer probably is no.

I needed to keep a backup for the buildpack incase the newly created one fails.
There is no option to download zip but we can rename existing buildpack to *_backup and then upload new one
cf rename-buildpack BUILDPACK_NAME NEW_BUILDPACK_NAME [-s STACK]

